# Create both remote and local git respositories on same system?

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, atlassian-sourcetree, git-config

I am having trouble with this. What I am trying to do is create a central git repository locally and then clone it to make a working copy. When I make changes to the clone and push the changes, I do not get any error in SourcTree but the changes does not get pushed. I don't see the change in the Central Repository.

I was getting various errors in the process, for example, SourceTree would complain this it executed `git status` on centeral repository

> fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree [duplicate]

I have to made my center repository bare, so that error goes away but still can't get `push` to work. I am not sure what is causing the problem. I experimented with it a bit but not successful. Is this something doable? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong.

(I do not to use host my central repository on clouds but I can move it to a difference PC. But I really want it both (Center and Working copy) on my own system)

Comment: How do you know the changes aren't getting pushed to the central repo?

Comment: @MagnusBäck When I visit the repo in Explorer, it does not show the new files that I added.

Comment: What Explorer, Windows Explorer? That's expected. To check whether a bare repository contains your commits, run `git log` inside that repository. SourceTree may or may not work for bare gits.

Comment: @MagnusBäck you are right. Also SourceTree does not work with bare gits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git happily supports what you with to do.
Follow these and I hope you dont get any problems:

1. Make your central repository bare (must)
2. List item
3. Clone this central repo on you system elsewhere. Use the absolute/relative paths central while cloning avoid using git://.
4. Do your work on local and push to bare.
5. If you want to see changes there are certain restrictions in git that you 'cant't' do in bare repo. So to see changes do a git-log or see it in gitk or source tree. You will see your changes.
   (Or you can clone your central after push, it will have your pushed changes)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, expanding on Mudassir answer

1. Create Bare Git Repository (Bare is Must)

> git init --bare my-project.git

2. Clone this Repository, do this one level above root

> git clone myproject-git myproject.clone

3. Open myproject.clone in SourceTree. Add files to it using any text editor and commit and push.

**Note that Bare Repositories doe not work in SourceTree**. If you open them, you will get an error. You can safely discard that error. [For more info](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository)